# Adding RadioButtons into TSNE

Tags: python-2.7

I am new in python programming. In the following link, the simple implementation of TSNE in python. 
https://lvdmaaten.github.io/tsne/

I am wondering how to add RadioButtons to represent all colors in a TSNE result in a list so I can select only certain number of color and see how they are distributed.

Here is the code:

```
      #
#  tsne.py
#
# Implementation of t-SNE in Python. The implementation was tested on Python 2.7.10, and it requires a working
# installation of NumPy. The implementation comes with an example on the MNIST dataset. In order to plot the
# results of this example, a working installation of matplotlib is required.
#
# The example can be run by executing: `ipython tsne.py`
#
#
#  Created by Laurens van der Maaten on 20-12-08.
#  Copyright (c) 2008 Tilburg University. All rights reserved.

import numpy as Math
import pylab as Plot

def Hbeta(D = Math.array([]), beta = 1.0):
"""Compute the perplexity and the P-row for a specific value of the precision of a Gaussian distribution."""

# Compute P-row and corresponding perplexity
P = Math.exp(-D.copy() * beta);
sumP = sum(P);
H = Math.log(sumP) + beta * Math.sum(D * P) / sumP;
P = P / sumP;
return H, P;


def x2p(X = Math.array([]), tol = 1e-5, perplexity = 30.0):
"""Performs a binary search to get P-values in such a way that each conditional Gaussian has the same perplexity."""

# Initialize some variables
print "Computing pairwise distances..."
(n, d) = X.shape;
sum_X = Math.sum(Math.square(X), 1);
D = Math.add(Math.add(-2 * Math.dot(X, X.T), sum_X).T, sum_X);
P = Math.zeros((n, n));
beta = Math.ones((n, 1));
logU = Math.log(perplexity);

# Loop over all datapoints
for i in range(n):

    # Print progress
    if i % 500 == 0:
        print "Computing P-values for point ", i, " of ", n, "..."

    # Compute the Gaussian kernel and entropy for the current precision
    betamin = -Math.inf;
    betamax =  Math.inf;
    Di = D[i, Math.concatenate((Math.r_[0:i], Math.r_[i+1:n]))];
    (H, thisP) = Hbeta(Di, beta[i]);

    # Evaluate whether the perplexity is within tolerance
    Hdiff = H - logU;
    tries = 0;
    while Math.abs(Hdiff) > tol and tries < 50:

        # If not, increase or decrease precision
        if Hdiff > 0:
            betamin = beta[i].copy();
            if betamax == Math.inf or betamax == -Math.inf:
                beta[i] = beta[i] * 2;
            else:
                beta[i] = (beta[i] + betamax) / 2;
        else:
            betamax = beta[i].copy();
            if betamin == Math.inf or betamin == -Math.inf:
                beta[i] = beta[i] / 2;
            else:
                beta[i] = (beta[i] + betamin) / 2;

        # Recompute the values
        (H, thisP) = Hbeta(Di, beta[i]);
        Hdiff = H - logU;
        tries = tries + 1;

    # Set the final row of P
    P[i, Math.concatenate((Math.r_[0:i], Math.r_[i+1:n]))] = thisP;

# Return final P-matrix
print "Mean value of sigma: ", Math.mean(Math.sqrt(1 / beta));
return P;


def pca(X = Math.array([]), no_dims = 50):
"""Runs PCA on the NxD array X in order to reduce its dimensionality to no_dims dimensions."""

print "Preprocessing the data using PCA..."
(n, d) = X.shape;
X = X - Math.tile(Math.mean(X, 0), (n, 1));
(l, M) = Math.linalg.eig(Math.dot(X.T, X));
Y = Math.dot(X, M[:,0:no_dims]);
return Y;


def tsne(X = Math.array([]), no_dims = 2, initial_dims = 50, perplexity = 30.0):
"""Runs t-SNE on the dataset in the NxD array X to reduce its dimensionality to no_dims dimensions.
The syntaxis of the function is Y = tsne.tsne(X, no_dims, perplexity), where X is an NxD NumPy array."""

# Check inputs
if isinstance(no_dims, float):
    print "Error: array X should have type float.";
    return -1;
if round(no_dims) != no_dims:
    print "Error: number of dimensions should be an integer.";
    return -1;

# Initialize variables
X = pca(X, initial_dims).real;
(n, d) = X.shape;
max_iter = 1000;
initial_momentum = 0.5;
final_momentum = 0.8;
eta = 500;
min_gain = 0.01;
Y = Math.random.randn(n, no_dims);
dY = Math.zeros((n, no_dims));
iY = Math.zeros((n, no_dims));
gains = Math.ones((n, no_dims));

# Compute P-values
P = x2p(X, 1e-5, perplexity);
P = P + Math.transpose(P);
P = P / Math.sum(P);
P = P * 4;                                  # early exaggeration
P = Math.maximum(P, 1e-12);

# Run iterations
for iter in range(max_iter):

    # Compute pairwise affinities
    sum_Y = Math.sum(Math.square(Y), 1);
    num = 1 / (1 + Math.add(Math.add(-2 * Math.dot(Y, Y.T), sum_Y).T, sum_Y));
    num[range(n), range(n)] = 0;
    Q = num / Math.sum(num);
    Q = Math.maximum(Q, 1e-12);

    # Compute gradient
    PQ = P - Q;
    for i in range(n):
        dY[i,:] = Math.sum(Math.tile(PQ[:,i] * num[:,i], (no_dims, 1)).T * (Y[i,:] - Y), 0);

    # Perform the update
    if iter < 20:
        momentum = initial_momentum
    else:
        momentum = final_momentum
    gains = (gains + 0.2) * ((dY > 0) != (iY > 0)) + (gains * 0.8) * ((dY > 0) == (iY > 0));
    gains[gains < min_gain] = min_gain;
    iY = momentum * iY - eta * (gains * dY);
    Y = Y + iY;
    Y = Y - Math.tile(Math.mean(Y, 0), (n, 1));

    # Compute current value of cost function
    if (iter + 1) % 10 == 0:
        C = Math.sum(P * Math.log(P / Q));
        print "Iteration ", (iter + 1), ": error is ", C

    # Stop lying about P-values
    if iter == 100:
        P = P / 4;

# Return solution
return Y;


if __name__ == "__main__":
print "Run Y = tsne.tsne(X, no_dims, perplexity) to perform t-SNE on your dataset."
print "Running example on 2,500 MNIST digits..."
X = Math.loadtxt("mnist2500_X.txt");
labels = Math.loadtxt("mnist2500_labels.txt");
Y = tsne(X, 2, 50, 20.0);
Plot.scatter(Y[:,0], Y[:,1], 20, labels);
Plot.show();
```